# How to get screen height in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

Hi Im just trying to get height using
`MediaQuery.of(context).size.height` but getting `FlutterError (No MediaQuery widget ancestor found. MyApp widgets require a MediaQuery widget ancestor. The specific widget that could not find a MediaQuery ancestor was: MyApp The ownership chain for the affected widget is: "MyApp ← [root]" No MediaQuery ancestor could be found starting from the context that was passed to MediaQuery.of(). This can happen because you have not added a WidgetsApp, CupertinoApp, or MaterialApp widget (those widgets introduce a MediaQuery), or it can happen if the context you use comes from a widget above those widgets.)`

```html
class BaseLayout extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: https://medium.com/@tungtran91/how-to-get-flutter-screen-size-e16d88332ed6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hy tony i found answer for your question
you need to add safeArea for it

```html
class BaseLayout extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
          body: Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Edited**

You have to provide it above the context of MediaQuery's context:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: BaseLayout()
    );
  }
}

class BaseLayout extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

create an own class and your error should be gone.

**original answer**

Do you have MaterialApp in your widget tree? MaterialApp provides MediaQuery.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      body:WhateverWidget
    );
  }
}
```

By the way... the solution is in your error code ;)

```
This can happen because you have not added a WidgetsApp, CupertinoApp, or MaterialApp widget (those widgets introduce a MediaQuery), or it can happen if the context you use comes from a widget above those widgets.)
```

Comment: Hi @MCB I have MaterialApp widget in my code still its showing me an error. updated my code you can refer with it